# permissions warnings for fn start from https://github.com/fnproject/fn

Tags: fn

Are these permission warnings fixable when starting Fn github project locally on my Docker in Docker (dind) instance following the directions on the github project: https://github.com/fnproject/fn ?  I installed via brew on a mac.

> $ fn start
>   mount: permission denied (are you root?)
>   Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
>   AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
>   mount: permission denied (are you root?)
>   time="2017-10-02T23:54:10Z" level=info msg="datastore dialed" datastore=sqlite3 max_idle_connections=256
>   time="2017-10-02T23:54:10Z" level=info msg="no docker auths from config files found (this is fine)" error="open /root/.dockercfg: no such file or directory"
>   time="2017-10-02T23:54:10Z" level=info msg="available memory" ram=7916183552
>   time="2017-10-02T23:54:10Z" level=info msg="Serving Functions API on address `:8080`"

```
    ______
   / ____/___
  / /_  / __ \
 / __/ / / / /
/_/   /_/ /_/
    v0.3.132
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww how is this not a question about development?

Answer (score 2):

Some of those warnings/messages are MacOS specific (ie: you won't see them on Linux). But they won't affect regular operations so you can safely ignore them.